# Trying to pass vars to PHP mail

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to pass a few SESSION variables to the PHP mail function so that it can be sent to the user with that information. The email system works, but the resulting email that arrives at the user has empty variables.

```
//Start the session and add the variables to it (these are viewed on page before sending email out):
<?php
  session_start();
  // Continue the session

  // retrieve session data
  $amount = $_SESSION["vprice"];
  $type = $_SESSION["vtype"];
  $member = $_SESSION["vmember"];

//Variables viewed on the page:
<p style="text-align: center;">
    Date: <?= date("Y/m/d")?><br>
    Member ID: <?= $member?><br>
    Order ID: <?= $abcOrderID?><br>
    Order Type: <?= $type?><br>
    Amount: <?= $amount?> &euro;</p>

// Get users email address to send to:
<form method="post" action="email.php">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
    Send Confirmation E-mail to: <input type="text" name="email" value="" /></p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /></p>
</form>

//Send the email using PHP mail()
<?php
    //if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

  //Email information
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $message = "Thank you for ......" ;

  // here we use the php mail function
  // to send an email to:
  // you@example.com
  mail( "info@abc.com", "Online Submission",$message, "From: $email" );
  }
?>

//In email.php I use the following to build the message:
$mail->Body    = "<p>Dear Member {$member1},</p><p>We have received your<strong> ABC payment</strong> and the purchased amount of {$amount1} in EUR will appear in your bank statement under the name ABC Ltd. Please keep this e-mail as a receipt for your records.</p><p>If you have any concern regarding this transaction, please do not hesitate to contact us</a>.</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Thank you,<br>ABC-Gym</p>";
```

I've been trying all sorts of things to fix it but nothing.
Any advice what is going wrong?

Thanks,
Andreas M.

Comment: Spoofing email with an arbitrary From field is a good way to destroy your sending reputation. You should always send from an address you control and can set SPF records for. Set a `Reply-To` field if you want to be able to reply to the original sender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have figured this out after some trial-and-error. I was mixing up php's mail() function and the added PHPMailer options in email.php and I should also note that I'm sending the email to the email address captured from the user's input.

This is what I changed in my response.php page for "Form" and "mail()":

```
<form method="post" action="email.php">
  <p style="text-align: center;">
        Send Confirmation E-mail to: <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
  <textarea style="visibility: hidden" name="message" id="message" rows="1" cols="1">
  <p>Dear Member (ID <?= $member ?>),</p><p>We have received your <strong>ABC payment</strong> for order #<?= $abcOrderID ?>|<?= $type ?> and the charged amount of <?= $amount ?> EURO will appear on your bank statement under the name ABC Ltd. Please keep this e-mail as a receipt for your records.</p><p>If you have any concern regarding this transaction, please do not hesitate to contact us</a>.</p><p>Thank you,<br>ABC Payments</p></textarea></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /></p>
    </form>
    <?php
      //if "email" variable is filled out, send email
      if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

      //Email information
      $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
      $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

      // here we use the php mail function
      // to send an email to:
      // you@example.com
      mail( "$email", "ABC Payment Submission", $message, "From: no-reply@abc.com" );
      }
    ?>
```

Now in my email.php of PHPMailer, here are the only changes (see comments):

```
// $email and $message are the data that is being
// posted to this page (email.php) from our php form (response.php)
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
//...
// $message is the forms message we have set in response.php
// page. We set this variable at the top of this page with:
// $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;
```

Working now!

Comment: Are you using `mail()` and phpMailer at the same time? Surely the whole point of phpMailer is to save you from having to ever have to use the old clunky `mail()` function. If you've got phpMailer in your code, use it for everything.

Comment: @simba, well that I realised now. Learning from errors, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
<?php
    //if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

  //Email information
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $message = "Thank you for ......" ;

  // here we use the php mail function
  // to send an email to:
  // you@example.com
  mail( "info@abc.com", "Online Submission",$message, "From: $email" );
  }
?>
```

you are assigning "Thank you for ......" to $message variable and sending that to mail() function which sends mail.

$mail->Body line in not executed and thats the reason for empty variables.
use

```
$message = "<p>Dear Member {$member1},</p><p>We have received your<strong> ABC payment</strong> and the purchased amount of {$amount1} in EUR will appear in your bank statement under the name ABC Sports Center Ltd. Please keep this e-mail as a receipt for your records.</p><p>If you have any concern regarding this transaction, please do not hesitate to contact us</a>.</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Thank you,<br>ABC-Gym</p>";
```

Comment: Mohd,

I tried what you suggested, but still the same -empty variables. Let me note that I have $message now in both the response.php(sender) page and in email.php itself (if that helps something).

Comment: Are you able to access $member1 and all other variable in email.php? Look at my mail.php code http://pastebin.com/bfCLFhWe

Comment: No, I don't get the variables in email.php -also, my file is all entries with $mail->From = $email; etc. Its confusing after having a look at yours. What should I prefer ?

Comment: If you are not getting the variables in email.php then obviously empty mails will be send, call mail() function where you have access to all the variables you are using.

Comment: I am, I'm calling it after the $message as so from the same file response.php:
mail( "info@abc.com", "ABC-Gym Payment Submission",$message, "From: $email" );

Comment: Once hardcode `mail( "info@abc.com", "ABC-Gym Payment Submission","testing", "From:".$email );` try this and check whether mail is sent or not.